Eyebrow Controller Bone Isn’t Parented To the BROW
I have an eyebrow armature bone which is the default bone for the eyebrow.
But I have created an extrude bone, because I need an eyebrow controller bone, but it seems like the eyebrow controller bone isn’t parented to the default eyebrow armature bone (default bone for eyebrow), and I’m helpless, I’ve tried so many methods but it not still parented.
Do you have any solution ?
VIDEO LINK

No need to ask for help, we are already there for that purpose :) Also, be careful with capitals as it is usually read as shouting.

Okay thanks for letting me know the rules

While files, images, and external links may be helpful additions to questions they should not remain the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, besides thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be searched for and indexed thus helping future users find it.

Did you try going into edit mode, select the eye brow bone and then the bone you extruded hit ctrl-p and select keep offset?

Yes that’s what I did, but I want to keep it offset, but it’s not parenting and I don’t understand wh

The only thing I can think is that maye it is already parented to something else, in which case you use alt-p to clear parent
